# What would be the best project structure for angular2/nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I currently have something like this:

```
root/
  node_modules/
  public/
    app/
    tsconfig.json
    index.html
  server/
    tsconfig.json
    app.ts
    someModule.ts
```

I want express server(server/app.ts) to give me access to `root/` but the best I get is `server/`(transpiled files go to to the same dir). I really would like to have server files in different directory then `root/`.

By the way I use typescript on nodejs because of great intellisense.